# No me funciona el intercep http

Tags: angular

estoy tratando de implementar un interceptor, vi por este sitio un ejemplo hace poco pero no me funciona. En el server me marca que el error existe, pero jamás me retorna al login, que estoy haciendo mal?

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('estoy acá!');
    sessionStorage.setItem('token', localStorage.getItem('token'));
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError(err => {
      localStorage.clear();
      sessionStorage.clear();
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: No he podido reproducir tu problema. A mí sí me navega a */login*

Comment: Puede tener algo relacionado con el tipo de error que retorno del server?                if (!tienePermiso) {
   httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, SIN_PERMISO);
  }
  else {
  if (!esValido) {
   httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, NO_VALIDO);
  }

Comment: Cualquier error 400 ó 500 va a parar al `catchError`. El *internal server error* es un 500, así que debe ir a parar ahí. Significa que el error está en otra parte, no este trozo de código que compartirste aquí.

Comment: Es raro, pongo un console log en luego del catch y no lo registra...

Answer (score 0):

creo que la estructura de tu interceptor esta mal, prueba de esta forma =>

```
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
           console.log('estoy acá!');
           sessionStorage.setItem('token', localStorage.getItem('token'));
        }
        return event;
      }),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
       catchError(err => {
          localStorage.clear();
          sessionStorage.clear();
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return throwError(error);
      }));
  }
```

Comment: Aparece esto: Argument of type '(error: HttpErrorResponse) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>